# How can I wait for <script> appended to body to finish executing

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, script-tag, ios-web-app

When the user clicks a button I need to append to my body an external script. This is the requirement.

Rookie question. Let's say that the external library creates a window.newLib variable. How can I be notified when the newLib variable is ready for me to use?

I tried this but onload does not get called:

```
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.innerHTML = 'window.test = 1; console.log("test defined.");';
  script.onload = "console.log('onload called.', window.test)"
  script.async = false;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
```

This works but it seems dirty to me. Is there a better way?

```
const injectScript = () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.innerHTML = 'setTimeout(() => {window.test = 1},10500); console.log("test defined.");';
  script.async = false;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

const nap = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const maxAttempts = 100;
const msNap = 100; // 10s timeout

const start = async () => {
  injectScript();
  let id = 0;
  while (true) {
    if (++id === maxAttempts) {
      throw(`Lib took too long to load: ${id * msNap}ms`);
    }
    if (window.test) break;
    await nap(msNap);
  }
  console.log('External lib correctly loaded.');
};
start();
```

Comment: `script.onload = "console.log('onload called.', window.test)"` is wrong. this needs to be assigned a function, not a string.

Comment: in other words, `script.onload = () => console.log('onload called.', window.test)`

Comment: True @Ultimater, but even if I do it does not get triggered.

Comment: Why not put your `<script src='yourJavaScriptPage.js'></script>` tags in your `<head>` and just use a `load` Event?

Comment: Because the requirement is that it needs to be loaded afterwards. More context: it's a Cordova App and the required library is downloaded as On-Demand Resource from Apple servers. Unfortunately I cannot change that.

Comment: Wrap your `injectScript` code in a `Promise`, resolve it when `script.onload` and reject when `script.onerror`. In your `start()` code, `await injectScript();`

Comment: Replace `script.innerHTML` with `script.src = 'data:text/html,window.test = 1; console.log("test defined.");';` in addition to my previous comment about onload taking a function. Onload doesn't appear to get called for inline javascript.

Comment: @Ultimater That works, thanks! What about remote URLs though, will it work in that case? PS. yep, work with links too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ultimater. This seems to work as expected:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'data:text/html,id = 0;while(true){ if(++id==1000000) break;} window.test = 1; console.log("test defined.");';
script.onload = () => console.log('onload called.', window.test);
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: script.onload, so simple, i cannot believe it took me this long to find this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const injectScript = () => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.innerHTML = 'console.log("Function loaded..."); window.postMessage({cmd:"loaded"});';
        script.async = false;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        setTimeout(injectScript, 3000);

        window.addEventListener('message', function(e){
            if(e.data.cmd === 'loaded'){
                console.log('external library loaded');
            }
        });
```